# How does server management software work?

Tags: c++

How does server management software work?

I was reading about this software, and I found that they can monitor CPU speed/temperature.

How can one do this in C++?

Comment: This is likely to be operating system-dependent.

Comment: That has nothing to do with C++. You need to use libraries or APIs for your operating system that provide this sort of information. And they are different for each type of OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally, motherboards come with device drivers that provide functionality to query the temp sensors and other motherboard parameters. These drivers can be accessed by other programs. For example, vendors like ASUS have rich GUIs that can present this info (by querying the driver) or background programs that can give you an alert when this crosses a threshold (by occasionally querying the driver). You could write something similar yourself, including server management software.

The main problem is that in a heterogeneous environment you could end up with different motherboards and thus different drivers. Some operating systems provide an abstraction layer for this functionality, so they can implement things like power management. I would also assume that modern motherboards have a more unified way of accessing this sort of information.

This is really not about C/C++, except that it is generally easier to access drivers from C/C++ than it is from languages like Java, C# or Python. In these cases, it is sometimes worth checking if there is a command-line based program on the motherboard CD that queries the driver, and then shell out, execute this program, and parse the returned string.